# Can we have a follow-up to "GPT on the platform: Data, actions, and outcomes"?

Tags: discussion, status-review, moderation, chatgpt

In answers to [GPT on the platform: Data, actions, and outcomes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389928/287976) there's been criticism about the methodology.

As the policy about suspensions and the strike is now ongoing for more than 30 days, can we have the same graphs updated to see the evolution?

There's a bunch of premise which should be visible as inflections in these graphs by now if they're correct.

From a comment, there's already interest in a subset of datas asked for here:

- [How have the ratio of large to small draft saves and the number of users who post at least 3 answers per week developed since the start of June?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/390700/287976)

Comment: "a bunch of premise which should be visible as inflections in theses graphs" Not totally sure. For example the company could argue that users have seen the error in their ways and given up on posting AI generated content and that persisted even after moderators stopped suspending users for it instead of users simply becoming more adept at covering their tracks. Whatever the statistics is (and it's good to have more data) it will probably always be subject to some interpretation.

Comment: @NoDataDumpNoContribution Well, yes, but the suspension or frequent answerers leaving should drop, right ? I'm interested in all the graphs, not just the "Golden standard" for GPT posts. (I agree the stats are just indicative, but well, now we have a point in time, having a second one would be great)

Comment: For some of these graphs I also already asked but didn't receive an answer yet: [How have the ratio of large to small draft saves and the number of users who post at least 3 answers per week developed since the start of June?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/390700/how-have-the-ratio-of-large-to-small-draft-saves-and-the-number-of-users-who-pos)

Comment: @NoDataDumpNoContribution Aww, sorry, totally missed it.

Comment: I'm a bit worried this is a "be careful what you wish for" situation; maybe more data will further divide us.  (Oh, and maybe the problems would have gotten worse: as diamond moderators stopped dealing with AI generated content, potentially less competent users took up the role.)

Comment: @tripleee I don't get why you link again this question which is in my question and the 3rd comment, something specific there I did miss ?

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones double sided sword indeed, with the change of policy and the strike we should see effects, if not it means the metrics were wrong. That will at least clear up the point about the metrics choose to  enforce the policy.

Comment: If it's not a duplicate, can you clarify how they differ? They both seem to ask for the same information.

Comment: @tripleee I mentioned it saying there's another question on __specific__ stat, this one is about getting the overall post, including the 'gold standard' one. Edited to make it more obvious